# My reveal on hover function doesn't work, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this function and i want it to on hover showe some text and change the background color, how can i do this ? I should also create div in html with txt right ? How the js function should look like ?

```js
$('.product-mouseover').mouseover(function() {
  (this).addClass('mouseover');
})
```

```css
/*products*/

#products {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

#products p {
  text-align: center;
}

#products img {
  padding: 55px;
  margin: auto;
}

#mouseover {
  background: #1ada00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products">
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
  <img id="product-mouseover" src="images/001-malware.png" alt="">
  <img id="product-mouseover" src="images/002-smartphone.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: "product-mouseover" is id, but your query searchs for class

Comment: I see a couple of issues such as having two elements using the same id. You need to reference id's by using the `#` instead of a `.` which are used for classes. Do you have any errors in your console?

Answer (score 2):

There were a few issues with your code (mostly just a mix-up of classes and IDs).

Firstly, `product-mouseover` should **not** be an ID. This *should* be a class (which you seem to have correct in the javascript).

In your CSS, `mouseover` should apply to the *class* mouseover, *not* an *id*.

Lastly, in your Javascript, change `(this)` to `$(this)`.

```js
$('.product-mouseover').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('mouseover');
})
```

```css
/*products*/

#products {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

#products p {
    text-align: center;
}

#products img {
    padding: 55px;
    margin: auto;
}

.mouseover {
    background: #1ada00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products">
                <h1>Products</h1>
                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
                <img class="product-mouseover" src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
                <img class="product-mouseover" src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
                </div>
```

Comment: The code I have posted is based on your own and works fine. Providing you have made the suggested changes correctly, the problem most likely stems from elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe problem is in css .mouseover ?